# Is there anyone who understand this symbol of Jetson nano based board schematics?

Tags: schematics

[image]

I am reading schematics of Jetson nano based board, that contains some symbols I have never seen before. Is there anyone understand this symbols?

you can find full schematics here: https://github.com/antmicro/jetson-nano-baseboard

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means that each of the differential pairs has a characteristic impedance of 100 ohms, in differential/coupled mode.

Comment: got it, thank you so much